# Task threadpoolexecutor disappeared suddenly after 10 minutes of running - python

Tags: python, django, threadpoolexecutor

The Task that created using ThreadPoolExecutor disappear if they are not completed within 10 minutes, this makes me unable to execute tasks that run for a long time.

I'm running a background scheduler in Django with an execution time window of every 5 seconds.

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(start_etl_caller, 'interval', seconds=5)


def execute_api(etl_id, endpoint, is_running, updated_at, threshold_time):
    try:
        print(f'start etl caller - etl_id : {etl_id}')
        x = requests.get(endpoint)
        print(endpoint, x.content)
        
        print(f'end etl caller - etl_id : {etl_id}')
    except:
        raise

    update_state(etl_id, False)

def start_etl_caller():
    etl_list = get_active_apis()

    threshold_time = (timezone.localtime() - timedelta(hours=1)).replace(tzinfo=None)
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()

    for etl_record in etl_list:
        if etl_record[2]:
            if etl_record[3] <= threshold_time:
                update_state(etl_record[0], False)

            continue
        
        update_state(etl_record[0], True)
        try:
            executor.submit(execute_api, etl_record[0], etl_record[1],
                            etl_record[2], etl_record[3], threshold_time)
        except:
            raise
```

The task is to call the API using ThreadPoolExecutor, so that processes do not wait for each other. However, if requests.get(endpoint) takes more than 10 minutes, the code after that will not be executed (print - update). My assumption is that tasks created using ThreadPoolExecutor will automatically disappear if the process does not complete before 10 minutes.

Is there any enlightenment on how I can solve this problem? I want my task to continue running even though 10 minutes have passed.

Thank You!